# 32-bit Divider in Verilog with Finite State Machine Control

Tags: verilog, state-machine, fsm

I am trying to implement a 32-bit divider in Verilog and I am having issues. A and B are the numbers to be divided. Here is my code so far. The output of the testbench is:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Also, what does it mean when the output is both Hi and Low at the same time? This is being implemented in EDAPlayground:

[Design and Testbench](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2uJv)

Comment: You dont seem to be asserting `start` in your waveform so its unclear what the problem might be

Comment: @Unn please take a look at the update. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if this is your only problem, but you are casing on `nextstate` in your combinational logic block in the control path. You should be casing on `state` (ie, it should not be `case (nextstate)` but `case (state)`)

You should also not be setting `load`, `run`, `err` and `ok` in both the `always @(posedge clk or negedge reset)` register block and the `always @(*)` combinational block in the control path, they should only be assigned from the combinational block.